# Where can I find error codes for kAFAssistantErrorDomain errors on iOS?

Tags: ios, sfspeechrecognizer

These errors are returned in iOS Speech Recognition.

But there does not seem to be a list of error codes anywhere on the web. Anyone know where they are?

Answer (score -1):

I'm not positive, but pretty sure that Nuance's SpeechKit 2 iOS is using the same framework, and here are their corresponding [error codes](https://developer.nuance.com/public/Help/DragonMobileSDKReference_iOS/Error-codes.html)